# I want to get from Germany to the US, what country can I quarantine in?

Tags: usa, schengen, covid-19, travel-ban

I'm in Germany and I need to get to the US. Since I'm not a US citizen or permanent resident, I can't travel directly because of the covid-19 travel ban. I want to find a country that

- Isn't covered by the US travel ban, i.e. isn't listed at https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/from-other-countries.html
- Allows travel from Germany
- Has active air travel from Germany and to the US right now.

Does anyone know if such a country exists? Is there a list of different countries' travel restrictions that could help me find out?

Alternatively, is there a way to spend 14 days at sea and then enter the US?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote.